# Single Git install, multiple environments (msys, cygwin, SourceTree, etc.)

Tags: git, windows

I have Git installed into Program Files (x86). The standard answer about global config file location is C:\Users[username].gitconfig. However, I'm using multiple environments like MinGW/MSys, cygwin or even Opscode Chef MSys. Git respects each $HOME setting and looks for .gitconfig in different locations.

How to define truly fixed location for Git configuration?

Comment: Future reference - consider looking at [where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go) to help gain a better understanding of what types of git questions go to which sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to create symbolic links from the real Git configuration file to each location expected by your various tools.

- On Cygwin or MSys you should be able to use `ln -s /path/to/real/config /file /path/to/expected/file/location`.
- With Windows paths you may have to use [the NTFS `mklink` command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link).

I believe that SourceTree has the capacity to use its own internal Git command, or one installed elsewhere. Tweaking this setting may help too.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've addressed this on a project I'm currently working on is as follows:

I have my *nix environment running under a VM on virtual box, I have the actual repo for my project in this VM, I have this repo set up with the usual suspects, pushing to github, local master etc etc.

I also have samba installed in my VM, and I have the repo folder exported via samba, this in turn shows up under the windows host that I'm running the VM on, and on my windows host I run TortoiseGit which when used against the exported folder see's the .git folder and works as expected.

The one thing that I DO have problems with though, is line endings.

Make sure that your git configuration is set up so that ALL line endings are transformed to a single type (Usually just a plain line feed), when I first set things up this really bit me on the behind, because I checked in some files from windows, which unknown to me my editor had changed all to windows line endings (code 13, code 10) , then when I later did a pull from inside the VM i got lots of changes I wasn't expecting, which in turn actually lead to me wiping out some earlier changes.

It's never a particularly good idea, to have two masters controlling a slave, but it can work as long as you tread very carefully.

Comment: Good point about line endings, though I've never had much luck letting Git modify them for me. Instead, I ensure that my editors are all configured to use one type (usually Unix style).

Comment: Yea it took me a while to figure it out, but once I got it sorted and left it alone, everything worked well after that.  For a long time I kept wondering who kept changing files that I'd not touched, the answer to it all was in the git config file in .git :-)